# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, syntax-error

Showing 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]' error. I couldn't figure out the issue. Here is the Markup and controller.js code. Thanks in advance. :)

HTML Markup

```
<nav ng-controller="menuListCtrl">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
        <a href="" title="">
          {{menu.id}}
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

controller.js

```
var plsControllers = angular.module('plsControllers', []);
plsControllers.controller('menuListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("data/menu.json")
       .success(function(response) {
         $scope.menus = response.records;
     });
}]);
```

[Error Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tYMX.png)

Comment: Do you have any other error log attached? Usually, the error log indicates the file and line of the error.

Comment: Please post the content of `menu.json`, my guess it that there is a syntax error in this file. When angular tries to parse the response from the server, an unexpected syntax error occurs

Comment: You should not use the minified version of angular while developing. You'd get much clearer error messages with the non-minified version.

Comment: Thank you very much guys.. as @apairet told the issue was in JSON file. But Now the data is not loading in page.

Comment: Yes @JBNizet I used Minified version and now changed. Thank you :)

Comment: No @Rodmentou There is no issue, Now Simply not loading the data in page.

Comment: Can you post the content of `menu.json`  I dont see any issue with your code

Comment: @apairet menu.json file ***************************`[ { "id":1, "name":"Home", "link":"#/home", "title":"Go to Home", "data-img":"img/tmp/home-bg.png" }, { "id":2, "name":"I,Me,Myself", "link":"#/i_me_myself", "title":"I Me Myself", "data-img":"img/tmp/home-bg.png" }, { "id":3, "name":"Portfolio", "link":"#/portfolio", "title":"Portfolio", "data-img":"img/tmp/home-bg.png" }, { "id":4, "name":"Expertise", "link":"#/expertise", "title":"Expertise", "data-img":"img/tmp/home-bg.png" } ]`